# How do you compile Mesos on OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, homebrew, osx-yosemite, mesos

I followed the directions outlined here: http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/

I checked everything out and then ran:

```
$ xcode-select --install
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
$ brew install autoconf automake libtool subversion maven
```

When I go into the mesos directory and run `./bootstrap` I get the following:

```
ln: .git/hooks/pre-commit: Not a directory
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --warnings=all -I m4
aclocal: error: aclocal: file '/usr/local/share/aclocal/libmcrypt.m4' does not exist
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Just thought I'd add that the selected answer solved the issue for me. After running `make check` I had 3 tests that failed. I ran it again and got 5 that failed. I exhaustively ran

```
$ ./bin/mesos-tests.sh --gtest_filter="NAMEOFFAILEDTEST" --verbose
```

and ended up with only three that failed because Docket tests are not supported on non-linux systems:

```
[  FAILED  ] ExamplesTest.TestFramework
[  FAILED  ] ExamplesTest.NoExecutorFramework
[  FAILED  ] ExamplesTest.PersistentVolumeFramework
```

Hope this helps others in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aclocal: error: aclocal: file '/usr/local/share/aclocal/libmcrypt.m4' does not exist
```

That file is provided by MCrypt. `brew install mcrypt`